# Issue between Unless .blank? and if

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Take a look at the following code snippets. *Keep in mind that `@product.name` is empty.*

**Code A**

```
<% if @product.name %>
  <div class="bonus">
    <h4>Bonus</h4>
    <%= @product.name %>                
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Code B**

```
<% unless @product.name.blank? %>
  <div class="bonus">
    <h4>Bonus</h4>
    <%= @product.name %>                
  </div>
<% end %>
```

From my understanding on how to use `if` and `unless` (thanks to [this](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/) article), both **Code A and B** should have the exact same function, except that **Code A** is the correct way of doing it according to best practices.

The problem with this is though that **Code A** displays generates the `<h4>Bonus</h4>` tag whereas **Code B** does not!

*How is this possible?*

Answer (score 6):

That's because in Ruby, an empty string is **true**.

Only `false` and `nil` evaluate to false, everything else is true in Ruby, including an empty string (unlike languages like Perl or PHP).

That's why Rails introduced `blank?` (and later its opposite `present?`)

From Rails' source code:

```
# An object is blank if it's false, empty, or a whitespace string.
# For example, "", "   ", +nil+, [], and {} are all blank.
#
# This simplifies:
#
#   if address.nil? || address.empty?
#
# ...to:
#
#   if address.blank?
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
end

# An object is present if it's not <tt>blank?</tt>.
def present?
  !blank?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

They're not the same.

- `blank?` checks for `nil` and white-space.
- `if` checks for truthiness. A string with only whitespace, including an empty string, is truthy.

The equivalent `if` statement would be `if @product.name.present?`

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Should I just use `unless ... .blank?` instead of `if` then? Or is there a way to check whether a value is empty using `if`?

Comment: @imjp What you're asking makes no sense--you check for an empty string using `if foo.blank?`, which is the opposite of what you said you wanted. Either use `unless foo.empty?`, or `if foo.present?`. The latter makes more sense in your case.

Comment: I did not know about the `.present?` method. I'm still new to Rails. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

`unless X.blank?` is *not* the opposite of `if X`!

`@product.name` is truthy unless it is set to `false` or `nil`. If it contains an empty string, program flow will still enter the `if` block and `<%= @product.name %>` will output an empty string.

`.blank?` is true for *empty* strings or strings which contain only whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Should I just use `unless ... .blank?` instead of `if` then? Or is there a way to check whether a value is empty using `if`?

Comment: @imjp Use `.present?` (example in answer).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the `.present?` method

Comment: You could use negation, since your intent *is* negation: `if !x.blank?`

Comment: @meagar But ew; `if x.present?` is more communicative and canonical.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby only `nil` and `false` are considered false values. So if condition in if statement is not `nil` or `false` the code inside will be executed. In your example A `@product.name` is empty string that is considered as true value by Ruby. So the code is executed.

On the other hand there is `blank?` method introduced by Rails. It returns false for:

- `nil`
- `false`
- `''` (empty String)
- `'   '` (whitespaced String)
- `{}` (empty Hash)
- `[]` (empty Array)

That's why you get `false` from `blank?` for empty `@product.name`.

And the opposite for [`blank?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) is [`present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method.

Comment: also you can use `empty?`. it's an alias of `blank?`

Comment: @NARKOZ, no, it's not. `empty?` is defined only for `Hash`, `Array` and `String` and checks for emptiness. So for whitespaced string `blank?` is true, but `empty?` is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts 'Empty string is truthy' if ''
#=> Empty string is truthy
```

That said, you can do:

```
<% if @product.name? %>
<% if @product.name.present? %>
<% unless @product.name.blank? %>
```

With a question mark at the end. That means "if @product.name is present" (<=> is not blank)

My preference goes to the first (`@product.name?`)